Managing Accumulative RAM Usage in PySpark Loop with applyInPandas
I'm running a loop over a grouped DataFrame with the applyInPandas function to save data from my analysis:
...

for i in range(10):
    df.groupby('size', 'color', 'width') \
      .applyInPandas(perform_curve_fit, schema=schema) \
      .write \
      .mode("overwrite") \
      .format("orc") \
      .save(f'results={i}', mode='overwrite', header=True)

...

However, I noticed that RAM consumption increases with each iteration. I'm manipulating large datasets, but here is a simplified version of my code:
import gc
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, upper
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, FloatType
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ProcessDataFrame").getOrCreate()

data = [(1, 'red', 3, 10, 50, 5), (4, 'blue', 6, 20, 60, 6), (7, 'green', 9, 30, 70, 7)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["size", "color", "width", "height", "weight", "depth"])


def func(df):
    df = df.withColumn("size", col("size") * 2) \
           .withColumn("width", col("width") + 1) \
           .withColumn("depth", col("depth") - 1)
    return df

df = func(df)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("size", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("color", StringType(), True),
    StructField("width", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("param", StringType(), True),
    StructField("value", FloatType(), True)])

def linear_model(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

def perform_curve_fit(pdf):
    size = pdf['size'].values
    width = pdf['width'].values
    
    popt, _ = curve_fit(linear_model, size, width)
    params_df = pd.DataFrame({'param': ['a', 'b'], 'value': popt})
    
    for col_name in ['size', 'color', 'width']:
        params_df[col_name] = pdf[col_name].iloc[0]
    
    return params_df[['size', 'color', 'width', 'param', 'value']]

for i in range(10):
    df = df.orderBy('size', 'color', 'width')

    df.groupby('size', 'color', 'width') \
      .applyInPandas(perform_curve_fit, schema=schema) \
      .write \
      .mode("overwrite") \
      .format("orc") \
      .save(f'results={i}', mode='overwrite', header=True)

    # gc.collect()
    # df.unpersist()

spark.stop()

For each i iteration, there is an increase in RAM consumption. I have attempted to use gc.collect() and df.unpersist() (commented out in the code) to clean up memory at each iteration without success.
Question:
How can I manage memory usage more efficiently in each iteration to prevent increasing RAM consumption? Any suggestions to free memory at each iteration are welcome.

Hi @guinomo, did you ever figure out what was happening with the memory utilization when using applyInPandas? I am trying to use applyInPandas with a dataset that is about 56 GB in size and I am noticing that the peak execution memory is extremely large compared to the size of each of the grouped partitions. The peak execution size if about 128 Mib and the shuffle read size is 3.8 MiB.
